# src2(la)tex doesnt really interpret mathematica notebook?

Tags: conversion, wolfram-mathematica

`src2(la)tex` is a linux application that takes input from different commercial file formats like `maple`, `mathematica`,... notebooks and emits them as `(la)tex` code.

But when I feed it a certain notebook it comments on `stdout` that it recognizes the file to be Mathematica notebook, but the resulting latex is simply the text contents of the .nb notebook prettyfied in `latex`, i.e. no interpretation of graphs etc...

Comment: You can convert Mathematica notebooks to LaTeX using Mathematica's File -> Save As ... menu item.  Mathematica comes with a LaTeX style file (in `SystemFiles/Include/TeX`) that will let you typeset the resulting output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that is how `src2(la)tex` is supposed to work.  It is really just a very simple pretty printer for source code, that will allow you to insert TeX commands in your code (like formula and even images).  You have to insert these in TeX format first, marking them by `{\ ... }`, `$ ... $` or `$$ ... $$`, then `src2(la)tex` will copy them directly to the output file without pretty printing them.  As far as I can tell, it cannot interpret any of the source code itself.

For example, if your source code contains:

```
void plot_f (float a, b) /* will plot the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$ from $a$ to $b$, 
                resulting in a plot like {\includegraphics{plot}} */
{
   /* do something */
}
```

it will be translated into

```
\documentstyle{article}
\begin{document}

\ifx\sevenrm\undefined
  \font\sevenrm=cmr7 scaled \magstep0
\fi

\newread\MyStyle
\openin\MyStyle=src2latex.s2t
\ifeof\MyStyle
  \closein\MyStyle
\else
  \input src2latex.s2t
  \closein\MyStyle
\fi

\ifx\gtfam\undefined
  \ifx\dm\undefined
    \ifx\tendm\undefined
      \def\mc{\null}
    \else
      \def\mc{\tendm}
    \fi
  \else
    \def\mc{\dm}
  \fi
  \ifx\dg\undefined
    \ifx\tendg\undefined
      \def\gt{\null}
    \else
      \def\gt{\tendg}
    \fi
  \else
    \def\gt{\dg}
  \fi
\fi
\ifx\sc\undefined
  \def\sc{\null}
\fi

\tt\mc 

\noindent
void{\tt\mc \kern0.500em}plot{\tt\_\kern.141em}f{\tt\mc \kern0.500em}(float{\tt\mc \kern0.500em}a,{\tt\mc \kern0.500em}b){\tt\mc \kern0.500em}\rm\mc {\tt /}{\tt *}\kern0.500em will\kern0.500em plot\kern0.500em the\kern0.500em function\kern0.500em $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$\rm\mc \kern0.500em from\kern0.500em $a$\rm\mc \kern0.500em to\kern0.500em $b$\rm\mc ,\kern0.500em 

\noindent
{\tt\mc \kern4.000em}{\tt\mc \kern4.000em}{\tt\mc \kern4.000em}\kern2.000em resulting\kern0.500em in\kern0.500em a\kern0.500em plot\kern0.500em like\kern0.500em  \includegraphics{plot} \rm\mc \kern0.500em {\tt *}{\tt /}
\tt\mc 

\noindent
{}{\tt\char'173}

\noindent
{}{\tt\mc \kern1.500em}\tt\mc {\tt /}{\tt *}\kern0.500em do\kern0.500em something\kern0.500em {\tt *}{\tt /}
\tt\mc 

\noindent
{}{\tt\char'175}

\noindent
{}

\rm\mc

\end{document}
```

Note that the result is in an old LaTeX 2.09 format.  Changing the first line and loading the `graphicx` package I was then able to produce this:

[image: result of src2latex]